# How Pass Data back a view controller in the stack?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I've seen a lot of questions in this category but they all seem to be be answer in the same manner, which is simply passing data between viewcontrollers, which isnt what I think I'm looking for.

I have VC1 that has data stored in it, under particular circumstance the user needs to entire information in VC2.  I need that info to be pass down the back to VC1, lets called the data "info"

I code I was hoping to use was like this.  I access the VC stack and assign the variables to an optional "info" variable (given at compile time the stack doesn't know what the VC type is one down on the stack.

```
let nav = self.navigationController
let nextView = nav?.viewControllers[(nav?.viewControllers.count)! - 1]
****//code that isn't working
nextView.info = self.info => Value of type 'UIViewController?' has no member 'info'

****//This works fine
nav?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: Doing `nextView.info = self.info` isn't passing data? Your issue is the exact same as those lot of questions and you should use the same approach.

Comment: None of the answers I found are like the one I've just accepted

Comment: Its totally your choice if you want to adopt erroneous approach. Did you face any issue using `prepare(for segue)` mentioned in many questions?

Comment: How could I use prepare for segue when popping a controller off the stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast it

```
if let let nextView = nav?.viewControllers[(nav?.viewControllers.count)! - 1] as? VCName {
   nextView.info = self.info
}
```

Comment: Does it fails to cast if nextView isnt of type "VCName"?

Comment: This approach has potential for crashes. Be careful to adopt this.

Comment: What is potential beyond the obvious?

Comment: there is no any potentials for crashes as the only threat is force unwrapping the count which will crash only if the count is 0 which won't happen as the process is embedded inside a navigationController that passed when code continues from optional  **= nav?**

Comment: @Sh_Khan `IndexOutOfBounds` is not an issue?

Comment: I say it won't even happen viewers always suspicious of **!**

Comment: Viewcontrollers is just an array so someone can remove an object so crash is vital. It’s not related to force unwrap.

Answer (score 2):

It's fragile to assume that you're in a navigation stack and that the view controller one below you is the one you need to talk to.

My guess is that the previous view controller pushed you, and gave you the data you're editing.

It would be better/cleaner to set up a delegate protocol between the 2 view controllers, and make yourself the new view controller's delegate before pushing it. Then it would just send a message to it's delegate to pass the data back.

Answer (score 2):

`nextView` is considered as it's superclass `UIViewController` because the array `viewControllers` from the `UINavigationController` is defined like so (`[UIViewController]`).

If your VC1 is of type `FirstVC` (subclass of `UIViewController`), you should cast it to its actual class to be able to "see" your additional properties. The same with your next view controllers. So, what happens if you do this?

```
let nextView = nav?.viewControllers[(nav?.viewControllers.count)! - 1] as? SecondVC
```

Of course, assuming your `nextView` is of class `SecondVC`. Remember that object oriented programming has **polymorphism**, in which all your view controllers are descendants of `UIViewController` and, thus, they **are** a `UIViewController` in general and these situations can happen.

Anyway, the correct way would be to define a protocol, make `FirstVC` conform to it, pass the first view controller as a parameter to the `SecondVC` and, in the second view controller, call the protocol method back to the first view controller when choosing an option. Something like:

```
protocol PassDataBackProtocol {
    var result: String
}

class FirstVC: UIViewController, PassDataBackProtocol {
    var result: String = "" {
        didSet {
            // Update your view
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let secondVC = segue.destination as? SecondVC {
            secondVC.firstVC = self
        }
    }
}

class SecondVC: UIViewController {
    weak var firstVC: PassDataBackProtocol?

    func didChangeValue(newValue: String) {
        firstVC?.result = newValue
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

If you're using `pushViewController(_:animated:)` instead of segues, then set `firstVC` before doing the push.

**EDIT:** I added the `weak` property to the back pointer, since it's important to avoid retain cicles.

Comment: You and I are saying essentially the same thing in our answers.

Comment: @DuncanC yeah, I just noticed that :)

Comment: You provided a lot more detail than I did so I up-voted your answer. **Question**: Why didn't you call the implementor of `PassDataBackProtocol` a delegate? This is really an example of the delegate design pattern.

Comment: @DuncanC I just tried to not go so technical, as the question is relatively basic and I thought the OP could be new at UIKit/Swift patterns. Anyway, I also wrote this relatively quickly since I was at work (missing some things like `weak` in the `SecondVC`). But you're right: this is the delegate pattern.

Comment: The weak back-pointer is important, as without it it will cause a retain cycle. You should edit your answer to include that and mention it in the edit.